# Flutter webview change viewport size

Tags: flutter, webview

Hi I created a webview with webview_flutter 4.x version.
I want to let iPad users see the mobile version as well.
Is there any option to manipulate the viewport in webview_flutter?
I want people using my app to always see the mobile version of the webview.

Thanks.